# Subset Notation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, real-numbers

I have just read that:
$$ \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} $$

But surely it is more appropriate that:

$$ \mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R} $$

Is true, right?

Comment: The second statement suggests that set equality is possible, but in each case we now the containment to be strict containment, so the first statement is more correct.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but $ \mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ right?

Comment: But usually the notation in the first chain also allows equality.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA as $\mathbb{N} $ implies 1,2,3,4...n, which are all in the set $ \mathbb{R} $ ,right?

Comment: It's akin to $1 \lt 2$ and $1 \leq 2$...

Comment: @Andrew I don't quite understand why?

Comment: In fact, $\subset $ and $\supset$ are also commonly used to denote $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$. For the strict inclusion, it's better to use $\subsetneq$ and $\supsetneq$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I think you mean $\subsetneq$, not $\nsubseteq$.

Comment: Generally, if not stated previously, the symbol $\subset$ mean $\subseteq$. If we want to says that something is a proper subset we write $\subsetneq$ to emphasize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $A,B$ be sets.
>
> We say that $A \subseteq B $  is true, if $a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$.
>
> Moreover, we say that $A \subset B$, if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \neq B$.
>
> This means that $A \subset B$ is a stronger condition: $A\subset B \Rightarrow A\subseteq B$.

Just like $<$ is a stronger version of $\leq$, e.g.: $1\leq 1,$ but $1 \not\lt 1$

In your case, $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are both true, since there are negative integers, non-integer rationals, and irrationals in $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q,$ and $ \mathbb R$ respectively.

Comment: But if for example, the number 3, $3 \in \mathbb{Z} $ and also, $ 3 \in \mathbb{Q}$ but from your definition, is the statement $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} $ more true as $ \mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Q} $, for all values?

Comment: Indeed, as I was trying to say, $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$ is a stronger statement than $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Q$, since it also says that $\mathbb Z \neq \mathbb Q$. Which means that there's a rational number which is not an integer.

Comment: Cheers, fully understood.

Answer (score 1):

It is not *wrong* to say that e.g. $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, just as it is not *wrong* to write that e.g. $2 \leq 3$. But it is more precise to write that $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, since we know that the inclusion is strict.